# Character classes strange behavior in alternations in regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a simple regular expression that recognizes a sequence of characters that are not columns or are escaped columns.
I.e:

```
foo:bar //Does not match
```

but

```
foo\:bar //Does match
```

By my knowledge of Regular Languages, such language can be described by the regular expression

```
/([^:]|\\[:])*/
```

You can see a graphical representation of this expression in the wonderful tool [Regexper](http://www.regexper.com/#%28%5B%5E%3A%5D%7C%5C%5C%5B%3A%5D%29%2a)

Using php's `preg_match` (that is based on the [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) engine), such expression does not match "foo\:bar".

However, if substitute the class with the single char:

```
/([^:]|\\:)*/
```

the expression matches.

Do you have an explanation for this? Is this a sort of limitation of the PCRE engine on character classes?

PS: Testing the first expression on [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), that is based on AS3 Regexp engine, does not offer a match, while changing the alternation order:

```
/(\\[:]|[^:])*/
```

it does match, while the same expression does not match in PCRE.

Comment: Question is tagged as PHP. Have you taken into account that backslash is the escape character in PHP strings?

Comment: Yes, of course, I've tried all combinations and non "\" escaping characters... :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: I think it is the source of the problem

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte The expreesion `/([^:]|E[:])*/` just behaves the same. But changing the order, with `/(E[:]|[^:])*/`, it matches...

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: because in the first expression the `E` is eaten by the `[^:]` and must stop at the `:`, but in the second expression the `E` is eaten by `E[:]` with the `:` and the regex engine can continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) accepts a regular expression pattern as a string, so you need to double escape everything.

```
^(?:[^:\\\\]|\\\\:)+$
```

This matches one or more characters that are not colons or escape characters `[^:\\\\]`, or an escaped colon `\\\\:`.

Why your first regular expression didn't work: `/([^:]|\\[:])*/`.

This matches a non-colon `[^:]`, or it matches `\\[:]` which matches a literal `[` followed by a literal `:` and then a literal `]`.

Why this works : `/([^:]|\\:)*/` ?

This matches a non-colon `[^:]`, or it matches a literal `\\:` so it effectively matches everything.

**Edit:** Why `/([^:]|E[:])*/` won't match `fooE:bar` ?

This is what happens: `[^:]` matches the `f` then it matches `o` then the other `o` then it matches the `E`, now it finds a colon `:` and it can't match it, but since by default the PCRE engine doesn't look for the longest possible match it is satisfied with what is has matched so far and stops right there and returns `fooE` as a match without trying the other alternative `E[:]` *(which is equal by the way to `E:`)* at all.

If you want to match the entire sequence then you will to use an expression like this one:

```
/([^:E]|E[:])*/
```

This prevents `[^:]` from consuming that `E`.

Comment: I've already posted, in the question, an expressions that matches. But I would like to know what is the problem in the original expression.

Comment: I do not get syntax errors, and substituting the "\" with a non-problematic escaping character, the problem persists. For example, `/([^:]|E[:])*/` does not match `fooE:bar`

Comment: @NicolòMartini Check my final edit, it explains the problem. If you need any more explanation please let me know.

Comment: And did you check my last comment? :)

Comment: @NicolòMartini You almost threw me off with this one, I will edit my answer to show you why `/([^:]|E[:])*/` won't match `fooE:bar`.

Comment: Can you make a new answer? Otherwise the comment discoussion will result broken...

Comment: @NicolòMartini Final version of the answer is finished, I advise you to read from the beginning and thank you for your patience.

Comment: Thank you, this is the point: "by default the PCRE engine doesn't look for the longest possible match it is satisfied". Answer accepted.

Comment: To clear up the answer, I think you can omit the section on escaping. I already meant that that expression was the string value php deals with, not its code-level representation (and in the piece of code where problem occurred escaping was correct). However, thanks again for the explanation, one should thinks twice what he means with "match" or "not match"...

Comment: @NicolòMartini You are very welcome, sometimes things get confusing and mixed together, but I think every thing is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. This allow the secuence `\\:` to have a chance before the negated character class `[^:]`.

```
^(?:\\:|[^:])+$
```

If you use the values in the alternation bar inverted as in `^((?:[^:]|\\:)+$` it will not match escaped colon `\:` because the first alternative will consume the slash (`\`) before the second expression have a chance to try.